# Rocky Linux and dynamic allocations

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, rocky-os

Does anyone have the following problem? When we do a dynamic allocation (accepted without bad_alloc) after a certain time (30 minutes) a memory leak occurs until reaching a ceiling.

```
#include <iostream>


#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 65535

int main()
{
    ///////////// Without this dynamic allocation no memory leak
    for(int i = 0; i < 6000; ++i)
    {
        new char[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    }

      // The std::cin below shows after 30 minutes that a memory leak is occurring
      // It increases until it reaches a ceiling
    
    char c;
    
    std::cout<< "Press key to exit"  << std::endl;

    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks a lot

I have tested under Rocky Linux 8.8 and the source has been compiled with gcc 8.5

Comment: Isn't allocating memory and losing the pointer the definition of a memory leak?  What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: This very simplistic program is just to show the problem.

In my software, there is a dynamic allocation made at start-up and released at the end.

I didn't understand that at cruising speed, when no more allocations were made, there was a leak that progressed until it reached a ceiling.
And as I reduced the code until there was nothing left, I noticed that with this very simple code, after 30 minutes the memory was increasing without any action being taken.
On the RedHat family only (centos, rocky).

Comment: Please provide your evidence of a memory leak.  Are you just measuring Linux's overcommit page allocation?  See https://serverfault.com/q/606185/115396